# Why does introducing this circuit in cause a higher voltage in existing circuit?

Tags: voltage, diodes

I have a Trans Control circuit that under normal conditions sends a 5V signal to a 9 ohm solenoid. The TCU controls this solenoid.

I have parallel wired a manually activated 5V supply that I activate using a 12V supply stepped down to 5V using a LM2596 adjustable stepper DC-DC converter.

Ive noticed now the factory TCU output has gone from 5V to 7V when automatically controlled??? After this I fitted a diode in line on my manually activated 5V Supply. The factory control then drops to 6V when automatically activated.

When I take away the manual input it operates as normal at 5V.

Why would this be occurring ??? Below is a poor attempt at a schematic to illustrate my point. and also a picture of the DC DC converter.

Thanks[image]

How can I bring the factory supply back to Stock Specs?[image]

Comment: What does the TCU do? Perhaps it senses that you've connected the 5V supply somehow?

Comment: How do you control your manual 5v supply?

Comment: Do you have any theory about why this happens?

Comment: The TCU controls the Transmission on my vehicle. I think it may be some kind of back feed that's why I fitted the diode which helped. I think perhaps a resistor may be required perhaps though not sure?

Comment: I control the supply via a momentary switch and relays

Comment: I don't get the "The TCU controls this solenoid." part. Your diagram shows the DC/DC converter powering the solenoid, without TCU (what is that anyway?) intervention. I get the impression that there is more going on than you tell. And where exactly is this 7V that you mention, and what is "automatic control", some form of PWM?